# RxJS Pipe Not Called With zip

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm zipping a three observables, each of the three observables has it's own "success" callback using `.pipe(tap() => {...});`.  This works fine when all three observables execute without error, but if one of the observables errors out, then none of the tap methods execute.  How can I have the tap methods always execute if that observable runs successfully?

```
var request1 = Observable.create(...);  //Pretend this one will fail (though request2 or request3 could also fail)
var request2 = Observable.create(...);
var request3 = Observable.create(...);

request1.pipe(tap(() => {
    //Unique success callback should always run if request1 succeeds, even if request2 or request 3 fails.
}));

request2.pipe(tap(() => {
    //Unique success callback should always run if request2 succeeds, even if request1 or request 3 fails.
}));

request3.pipe(tap(() => {
    //Unique success callback should always run if request3 succeeds, even if request1 or request 2 fails.
}));

var observable = zip(request1, request2, request3);
observable.subscribe(() => {
    //Do something when all three execute successfully
});
```

Comment: how is this related to angular?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Did you downvote because I used `Observable.create` instead of `httpClient.post` in my example?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is expected and the appropriate behavior for what you're dealing with. You probably want to look at using piping the `catchError` lettable into each of your requests and returning an empty observable.

```
request1.pipe(tap(() => {
    //Unique success callback
}), catchError((err) => {
    return empty();
}));
```

That way you handle the error of that observable without breaking the new `zip`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, though I don't think it's what I'm looking for.  I updated my comments above for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelSolati is nearly correct, except

- you should catch and return a value, e.g `null` if you wish to see output in `subscribe()` - because zip won't fire with `empty()`
- your `tap()` callbacks are not in the `zip()` pipeline, they are separate branches which are not subscribed to, so are never activated.

Note that with changes to rxjs versions, the imports can get a bit tricky, for example `zip` is available as a function and as an operator.
With the `rxjs.umd.js` cdn used in the snippet below, I initially used the operator by mistake and it doesn't throw an error (but does not work).

I note from comments above you are doing this in an **Angular** context. If
you still have a problem, please post your full Angular module with imports and we can resolve the difficulty.

```js
console.clear()
//console.log(rxjs)

// Get the operators and creators
const tap = rxjs.operators.tap
const empty = rxjs.empty
const zip = rxjs.zip
const catchError = rxjs.operators.catchError
const of = rxjs.of
const throwError = rxjs.throwError


//var request1 = of(1)
var request1 = throwError('error') 
var request2 = of(2)
var request3 = of(3)

var req1 = request1.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('request1')),
  catchError((err) => { 
    console.log('request1 has error')
    return of(null) 
  })
);

var req2 = request2.pipe(
  tap(() => { console.log('request2');})
);

var req3 = request3.pipe(
  tap(() => { console.log('request3');})
);

var myObservable = rxjs.zip(req1, req2, req3);
myObservable.subscribe(
  result => { console.log('result', result) }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `catch` block in your code where you can track the errors.

```
request1.pipe(tap(() => {
    //Unique success callback I want to run if request2 succeeds.
    //It should still run if request1 fails
}),
    catchError(// Error occured)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, though I don't think it's what I'm looking for.  I updated my comments above for clarification.